# How to resolve this direct cause of indexing key error?

Tags: indexing

I am getting this error which is of indexing key error which is telling "If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error" will raise, How to resolve this?

If anyone know how to resolve such type of errors, then let me know.

Comment: You aren't giving anyone any context here. Programming language? What did you do? Exact stacktrace?